# How to configure partitions for installing ubuntu parallel to windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation

My hard drive has 3 partitions (+1 with the windows bootloader). Windows is installed on C, some personal data is on D and my E partition is completely empty and (ntfs) formatted. I want to install Ubuntu Linux on the E partition. Also, it would be good if I was able to access content on my D (and maybe even C) partitions from the Ubuntu system.

Images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH4TT.jpg

My questions:

1: Where should I install the Ubuntu bootloader (should I do it on C, could I do it on E, will it harm my data on C/E if I do it there)

2: How should I configure each partition (how it is used by Ubuntu, see the dropdown menu in the images), so that Ubuntu will be installed like I want? (Installation on E, possibly access to D and C)

Comment: If you are trying linux(ubuntu) fir first time i will suggest to use vmware or virtual box. This will help you to understand how partitioning work in linux and risk will be almost none for your data. If you still want to dual boot your machine then i can try to explain how to do it.

Comment: I already used linux in virtual machines, and I backed up my data. It's pretty important for me to have linux installed on my computer

Answer (score 1):

You should delete your `/dev/sda4` partition using `-` option during installation and then you can do partitioning on that drive. You can partition that /dev/sda4 further into /boot, /, /home etc partitions. Also since you have already 4 partitions made. These will be all logical partitions.

As far as installing boot loader it should be installed on `/dev/sda` not on any partition but on hard disk itself. At time of booting it will give you option to choose from windows or ubuntu.

NOTE:- One should always take backup of their data before doing this.